# Can I add Firebase to Flutter plugin or package?

Tags: firebase, flutter, plugins, package

I have multiple applications with similar functionalities (the entire applications are based on firebase), like (login, register, storage,..etc) can I create a plugin or a package in which I can put all my firebase related code and reuse it in the applications?

The option of creating one application with different interfaces (need to hear pros and cons)

Comment: Seems like a nice idea.

Comment: Can I add firebase to the packages? I have searched the internet and I can only find "how to add firebase to a flutter application"

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages

You can just create a package by following the guide above and reuse it in any application you want. I wish I can create a example. But, that will take sometime .

Comment: @Sergi, were you able to add firebase to the plugin/package?. i am also looking for the same

Comment: @SravanKumar I am really sorry about the late reply
But I couldn't 
I just made it easier to transform the repeated code

Comment: @Sergi Are you able to find it?

Comment: @kunjkanani sadly no